# MySQL. Relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design

Thanks in advance for your answer. I am trying to tune my db skills.

I have 3 tables:

Brand, Model and Item.

All models belongs to a brand, but an item can have a brand but not a model.

I have 2 questions:

1. From a programming point of view I just add brandId as foreign key and ModelId just as a field to Item table.But from database design perspective, I guess this is the wrong approach. How I should manage it?
2. In the case that an Item always have a model and brand. I usually only add modelId and from it I can get brandId, but I have been seeing a growing wave where both fields would be added to item table, again, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your question hits a 'gray area'; there is not an overwhelmingly 'right' way to design the schema.

When the question is asked about city + state + country, I say:  Have one `Locations` table that contains all 3 columns.  And use `country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`.

I also say "normalize, but don't over-normalize".

There are 'religious wars' fought over your question.  There are valid points on either side.  Flip a coin, implement it, then learn from the decision.

Better yet, implement both ways - writing the `CREATE TABLEs`, the `INSERTs`, the `SELECTs`, etc.

Still better is to implement both, but have a "database abstraction layer" in your code that hides the choice from your application code.  Coming up with a single abstraction for your app that works with either backend will be the best lesson here.

Comment: awesome, i will experiment for sure. thanks for taking the time

Comment: maybe you can help me with this question?: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196059/mysql-creating-an-store-procedure-from-a-php-method